# C program to find average, what is wrong in code?

Tags: c, average

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void){
double sum = 0;
int ii = 0;
char buf[256], *token;
printf("Enter the numbers to average on a single line, separated by space and press enter when done\n");
fgets(buf, 255, stdin);
token = strtok(buf, " ");
while (token != NULL)
{
    sum += atof(token);
    ii++;
    token = strtok("", " ");    // Get next number
}
printf("Average is %lf", sum / (double)ii);
return 0;
}
```

The above program is to find avg of numbers given by the user. The program have no errors. I have these problems with code:

When you run it, it will ask you to enter the nos. separated by spaces for which you find the average. When you enter numbers separted by spaces-
for example you entered- 9080 5749 4343 8509 9790 , then it will print the first number as answer (i.e 9080).
If you enter 9497 795 88 then it will print "Average is 9497.00000000". If you enter 27 59 05 then it will print "Average is 27.0000000" and so on..

Can anyone tell whats wrong with it? I've tried replacing gets() of code with getline() but it gives 'Segmention Fault' error on output.

Comment: The first param of strtok have to be NULL after the first iteration.

Comment: Check [this code](http://codepad.org/fkZ6MHAS)

Comment: Note: recommend `fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)` instead of `fgets(buf, 255, stdin)`.  1: 256 is what should be passed here rather than 255, fgets() knows to only store 255 char and then a \0.  2: better to use `sizeof buf` rather than 256, so when the buffer size changes, you only have 1 place in code to update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the way that you are calling `strtok`:

> On a first call, the function expects a C string as argument for str, whose first character is used as the starting location to scan for tokens. **In subsequent calls, the function expects a null pointer** and uses the position right after the end of last token as the new starting location for scanning. (emphasis is mine)

You are passing an empty string `""` instead of `NULL`, that's why the results include only the first item the user has entered.

Note: Since `strtok` is not re-entrant, you should consider switching to [`strtok_r`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r).

Comment: @user2583127 All you need to do is replacing `token = strtok("", " ")` with `token = strtok(NULL, " ")`.

Comment: that did the work thx! :) I have 1 more question, in line 7, can i assign limit of buf to infinite? if yes then how?

Comment: @user2583127 No, you cannot assign the limit to more than what's allocated. You can allocate more, a lot more, but there would still be a limit, because C library does not support automatic re-allocation of the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

The code needs to be changed as below:

instead of
token = strtok("", " ");

use as below:
token = strtok(NULL, " ");